# Java-Array Splitting

Tags: java, split

I have array of string `{"All-Inclusive,All Inclusive","Luxury,Luxury","Spa-And-Relaxation,Spa & Relaxation"}`

I want to split them based on "," with two arrays, first array `{"All-Inclusive","Luxury","Spa-And-Relaxation"}` and a second array `{"All Inclusive","Luxury","Spa & Relaxation"}`.

Can you kindly suggest how can it be done?

Comment: atleast write a main method with some code, so that we feel that you are also trying!

Comment: show us what you have tired so far?

Comment: you might want to iterate through the first list, and for each element extract the part after "," and insert it into another list.

Comment: Iterate over arrays, use `split(",")` on each string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate your array of `String`(s). For each element, call `String.split(String)` and that will produce a temporary array. Make sure you got two `String`(s) from the array and then assign it to your output `first` and `second` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = { "All-Inclusive,All Inclusive", "Luxury,Luxury",
            "Spa-And-Relaxation,Spa & Relaxation" };
    String[] first = new String[arr.length];
    String[] second = new String[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        String[] t = arr[i].split("\\s*,\\s*");
        if (t.length == 2) {
            first[i] = t[0];
            second[i] = t[1];
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("First = %s%n", Arrays.toString(first));
    System.out.printf("Second = %s%n", Arrays.toString(second));
}
```

Output is

```
First = [All-Inclusive, Luxury, Spa-And-Relaxation]
Second = [All Inclusive, Luxury, Spa & Relaxation]
```

Comment: I could proceed till String App_AllBestForLinks[]={"All-Inclusive,All Inclusive","Luxury,Luxury","Spa-And-Relaxation,Spa & Relaxation"};
    
    String[] App_AllBesturl=new String[n];
    
             for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
              {
               m=App_AllBestForLinks[i].split(",");